# How to rotate one vector on another?

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, geometry

I need to place vector b(p2, p3) on vector a(p1, p2)
Could you advise me some formula?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The order of the point matters here. You have them line up both starting at P2, but the beginning point of vector a is P1, not P2.

Comment: Don't understand the question. I have always rotate the second vector to the first.
In that case (p1,p2) - first vector and (p2, p3) - second

Comment: Try `P3' = P2 - (P2 - P1) / ||P2 - P1|| * ||P3 - P2||`, which is equivalent to `b' = -a / ||a|| * ||b||`, as the math-ish formula

Comment: You can get the angle between the two using the dot product formula.  Rotate to preserve the right hand rule: the cross product should be out of the plane.

Answer (score 1):

If you need angle to rotate, calculate it as

```
dAx = P1.x - P2.x
dAy = P1.y - P2.y
dBx = P3.x - P2.x
dBy = P2.y - P2y
an = atan2(dAx * dBy - dAy * dBx, dAx * dBx + dAy * dBy)
```

but your picture perhaps shows that you need to just make vector with length of P2P3 but collinear with P2P1. In this case:
-calculate length of both vectors
-find normalized direction vector for P2P1 - get it's component nad divide by vector length
-multiply components of normalized vector by length of P2P3